# Bootstrap: Where or where has text-center gone?

Tags: bootstrap-4

Could someone tell me where text-center (previously text-xs-center) has gone with this release? Has the name been changed again? If so, what is it now and which sass module would I find this in?

Comment: Which release? The docs indicate `text-center` is the right class: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/typography/#alignment

Comment: It's still there? [Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/text/#text-alignment)

Comment: As for where it is in the code, https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/1846ab34f68c9ac28254915ebcb885b7aef5d25e/scss/utilities/_text.scss#L19

Comment: The name hasn't been changed, and if you're using the bootstrap-sass package there's just the one module for all the classes (except for the icon fonts which is bootstrap-sprockets).

Comment: I tagged this as bootstrap-4, so bootstrap-4 (beta) is the version I'm referring.

Comment: and no... I'm grepping through the entire file set under bootstrap/scss and there is no reference to text-center at all.

Comment: Maybe your problem has something to do with this commit? Typography has been renamed to Text. https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/commit/b5a2441f1bd5c76a65d68f548b5ef9575c27666a

Comment: And yes, https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/scss/utilities/_text.scss does actually contain .text#{$infix}-center

Answer (score -2):

Okay, found it in the bootstrap/scss/utilities/text module.